# Not able to get low stock item on basis of this query

Tags: php, mysql

Here I have a table with column item_quantity and other is item_low_stock, I need to get item they either equal to low stock or less than to low stock.

Here is table:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------
|            item_id             item_quantity   item_low_stock
+-----------------------------+-------------------+--------
| 1                           | 5                 |    5 
| 2                           | 10                |    9 
| 3                           | 6                 |   10 
+-----------------------------+-------------------+-------
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT item1.item_id as itemId, item1.item_quantity as qty, item1.item_low_stock as lowStock
FROM `eot_item` as item1
INNER JOIN eot_item as item2 ON item1.item_id = item2.item_id
WHERE item1.item_quantity <= item2.item_low_stock
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Why you join the same tabel?

Comment: @Siva because both column have on same table

Comment: How do you get to know the lowest stock. Do you have a pre defined value or you need to get it from the same table. If yes then the lowest value is for the same record or for any other record too.

Comment: Same table means this is enough, Please try this.
`SELECT item1.item_id as itemId, item1.item_quantity as qty, item1.item_low_stock as lowStock
FROM `eot_item` as item1
WHERE item1.item_quantity <= item1.item_low_stock
LIMIT 10`

Comment: I defined the lowest value at the time of add item.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your query returns row 1 and row 3 as expected and so does the solution provided by @Channaveer Hakari - what do you think is wrong with that?

Comment: @P.Salmon But it's give all three rows. I need only 1 and 3 rows

Comment: @rawathemant nope it doesnt output all the 3 rows, but returns only 2 rows as expected. Please find the screen shot attached.

Comment: @rawathemant not possible given the data provided.

Comment: I found the solution for this error, Its because i take field type varchar instead of int. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query.

Since you have defined the lowest value in another column no need to do the inner join.

> NOTE - Just for the sake of demonstration I am using * (ie select all
>   columns, please get only the respective columns for faster execution)

I hope your updating the **item_quantity** after every change in the quantity

```
SELECT *
FROM `eot_item`
WHERE item_quantity <= item_low_stock
```

Comment: whats the error that your getting. Can you please post some output examples of what your tables looks like and whats your expected output. So that I can help you better

Comment: @rawathemant can you please try the edited query once again and let me know whats the issue that your getting

Comment: Please don't include pictures in answers where text would work just fine.

Comment: @Strawberry since he was not able to get the query working I posted the working one

Comment: You posted pictures. Please don't. If you like, you can post a link to an sqlfiddle instead.

Comment: @Strawberry Okay will remove them right away and will include external links